# Почему .delay() не работает в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
    var bh = $("body").height();
    $("body").css('height', bh + 1).delay(2000).css('height', 'auto');
});
```

Если `.fadeIn()`, `.fadeOut()` поставить, то все ок, а с `.css()` - сразу `auto` ставится.

Comment: Неужели сложно справку почитать? 

http://api.jquery.com/delay/ - первый же коммент и объяснение, и решение.

Comment: @равнодушный Я смотрел. Я не понимаю, что не так. Вроде сделал по правилам...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> .css() wil always happen straight away
> as it doesn't go into the 'fx' queue.
> You therefore need to add it to a
> queue for it to be delayed like this:

```
$("body").css({"background-color": "#FF0000"})
.delay(1000).queue(function () {$(this).css({"background-color": "#ABC"});$(this).dequeue();})
.delay(1000).queue(function () {$(this).css({"background-color": "#FFFFFF"});$(this).dequeue();})
```

Или для Вашего кода как-то так:

```
$("body").css('height', bh + 1).delay(2000).queue(function () { $(this).css('height', 'auto'); $(this).dequeue();});
```